# Angular loadChildren com sub pasta erro ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Tags: angular

tenho o seguinte cenário.

Meu app.routes.ts tenho:

```
{ path: 'workflow', loadChildren: () => import('./workflow/workflow.module').then(m => m.WorkflowModule) }
```

Na minha pasta workflow tenho o arquivo workflow.routes.ts com as seguintes informações:

```
import { InboxComponent } from "./inbox/inbox.component";
import { UsuarioComponent } from './cadastros/usuario/usuario.component';

export const WorkflowRouterConfig: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: WorkflowComponent,
        children: [            
            { path: 'inbox',canActivate: [AuthService], component: InboxComponent },
            { path: 'usuario',canActivate: [AuthService], component: UsuarioComponent }            
        ]
    }    
];
```

no meu nav bar:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/workflow/usuario']">Usuário</a>
```

apresenta o erro ao clicar no link:
Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

o problema que vejo é que estou tentando acessar uma subpasta dentro no workflow chamada cadastros dentro dele tenho comente usuario.

Comment: Tem um router  outlet dentro do seu WorkflowComponent?

Comment: Sim segue,  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class WorkflowComponent {
  public constructor(){ }
}